# How do you convert encoded JSON string properties when calling JsonConvert.SerializeObject?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a POCO with some string properties that contain encoded JSON objects.

When I call JsonConvert.SerializeObject, I would like to convert these strings back into JSON and have Json.NET serialize them as embedded JSON objects.

How do you convert encoded JSON string properties when calling JsonConvert.SerializeObject?

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class LogAction
{
    // other properties
    public string Request { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a line of code that sets the Response property:

```
Response = actionExecutedContext.Response?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

I include this line of code to demonstrate that the property is being set using a method – `ReadAsStringAsync` which returns an encoded JSON string. In my case it will always be an encoded JSON string or it will be null.

Ideas?

Comment: Use the type JRaw instead of string for JSON data.

Comment: I can’t do that. I am using this class as an entity in entity framework. I wouldn’t mind having an attribute if there was one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a property-specific converter by putting the converter attribute above your JSON properties:

```
public class LogAction
{
  // other properties
  [JsonConverter(typeof(RawJsonConverter))]
  public string Request { get; set; }
  [JsonConverter(typeof(RawJsonConverter))]
  public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

The converter would be the following and writes strings as is assuming them to already be JSON.

```
public class RawJsonConverter: JsonConverter
{
  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    return JObject.Load(reader).ToString();
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    writer.WriteRawValue((string)value);
  }

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
    return objectType == typeof(string);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ckuri set me on the right path so I marked his response as the answer, but I ultimately settled on a different implementation.

Here's why I changed the implementation:

- The encoded string could be an object or it could be an array.
- I wanted a clear error message if the encoded string property could not
  be parsed.
- I was seeing some buffer overrun issues using the JToken.Load(reader) call.

I hope this will help someone else.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The RawJsonConverter is used to convert an object's string-typed properties containing valid string-encoded
    /// JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) into non-encoded strings so that they may be treated as JSON objects and
    /// arrays instead of strings when their containing objects are serialized.
    /// Note that the properties of the object must be decorated with the JsonConverterAttribute like this:
    ///     [JsonConverter(typeof(RawJsonConverter))]
    ///     public string EncodedJsonProperty { get; set; }
    /// </summary>
    public class RawJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            try
            {
                var value = serializer.Deserialize<String>(reader).Trim();
                return JToken.Parse(value).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not parse JSON from string in RawJsonConverter.", ex);
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteRawValue((string)value);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(string);
        }
    }
```